Blazor syntax for Renderfragment literal without 'root container'
In a Blazor component, when there is some html that repeats but it's not complex enough to justify the creation of one extra component, I put this html into a RenderFragmet private field or function, so I can reuse it along the component. A simplified example:
<ul>
    @menuOption("Menu 1")
    @menuOption("Menu 2")
    @menuOption("Menu 3")
</ul>

@code {
    private RenderFragment menuOption(string title) =>
        @<li class="text-lg font-bold bg-blue-500 px-4 py-2">@title</li>;
}

But I don't know how to write the RenderFragment literal if there is no 'root element' for the RenderFragment. For example, in React I can do:
const fragment = <>
                   <div>1</div>
                   <div>2</div>
                   <div>3</div>
                 </>;

but in Blazor I can't do:
private RenderFragment fragment = @<>
                                      <div>1</div>
                                      <div>2</div>
                                      <div>3</div>
                                   </>;

Is there something similar in Blazor?
Regards.

You can use the text element, it does not render anything.
private RenderFragment fragment = @<text>
                                      <div>1</div>
                                      <div>2</div>
                                      <div>3</div>
                                   </text>;


Thanks, it works as expected. I missed this part of the documentation.

I am not sure it is documented for Blazor - but it was approved some time back in a github issue by one of the Blazor team, and appears in this test in the aspnetcore repo being used in this way:

It's documented here Explicit delimited transition. I don't know when it was added to docs, but I don't remember it from when I read the documentation a few years ago.

Yes but that is for razor pages... they don't make it clear that it is available in razor components

you can use renderTreeBuilder. It is basically opening html tags and adding content and attributes via methods. Check out microsoft official docs about it.
I have many UIhelpers classes written in C# (not razor syntax), it s quite helpful.  Below is an example. Methods are invoked in component via @ razor syntax.
 /// <summary>
 /// Convert number to string so that one lenght digit takes space of 2 digit numbers
 /// 
 /// Example result
 /// 
 /// <span>
 ///    NrInString
 /// </span>
 /// 
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="nrInt">Nr to be converted to markup</param>
 /// <returns>RenderFragment</returns>
 public static  RenderFragment FormatNumber(int nrInt) => builder =>
 {
     string nr = (nrInt).ToString() + ".";

     builder.OpenElement(1, "span");  

     if(nrInt < 10)
     {
         builder.OpenElement(2, "span");
         builder.AddMarkupContent(3, "&nbsp;");
         builder.CloseElement();
     }

     builder.OpenElement(4, "span");
     builder.AddContent(5, nr);
     builder.CloseElement();

     builder.CloseElement(); 
 };

